# Force return type narrowing in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, covariance, narrowing

It is possible to narrow return type in overriding methods in Java.

But is it possible to force this narrowing during declaration?

For example, this may be good in the pattern, where inner class is subclassed simultaneously with outer one:

```
public class Try_ForceNarrow {

    public interface IMember {

    }

    public interface Container<M extends IMember> {
        M createMember();
    }

    public static class A implements Container<A.Member> {

        @Override
        public Member createMember() {
            return new Member();
        }

        public class Member implements IMember {
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A implements Container<B.Member> {

        @Override
        public Member createMember() {
            return new Member();
        }

        public class Member extends A.Member {

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

This code fails compile with an error of "The interface Container cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments".

How to avoid this?

Of course, I can just write

```
public static class B extends A  {

        @Override
        public Member createMember() {
            return new Member();
        }

        public class Member extends A.Member {

        }

    }
```

But this way I can forget to override `createMember()` and violate the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

And what about `A<T> implements Container<T>` ? You can restrict T further as you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you want each subclass `C` to have a `createMember` factory method that returns a new object that has the same type.  The problem is that if `C1` provides a factory method that returns `C1`, and then `C2` extends `C1`, there's no way to force `C2` to provide its own method--it could just inherit the one from `C1`.

I don't think there's a solution that will catch errors at compile time, but maybe you can do something that catches the error at run time:

```
abstract class MemberBase {

    protected abstract MemberBase doCreateMember();
    protected abstract Class<?> memberClass();

    public MemberBase createMember() {
         MemberBase result = doCreateMember();
         if (result.getClass() != memberClass()) {
             throw new RuntimeException("createMember returned the wrong class");
         }
         return result;
    }

}
public static class A extends MemberBase {

    @Override
    protected Member doCreateMember() {
        return new Member();
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> memberClass() {
        return Member.class;
    }

    public class Member implements IMember {
    }
}
public static class B extends A {

    // If you forget to define this, the doCreateMember in A will be
    // inherited, but it will return the wrong class and lead to a
    // run-time exception
    @Override
    protected Member doCreateMember() {
        return new Member();
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> memberClass() {
        return Member.class;
    }

    public class Member extends A.Member {
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, and I'm not sure it accomplishes what you are looking for.  Plus I may have gotten some syntax wrong.  But maybe this, or a modification of it, might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this fulfills what you are trying to do.

You can create a new abstract class that implements `Container` which allows you to continually extend or narrow the generics, but you need to declare each class static:

```
class Try_ForceNarrow {

    public interface IMember {

    }

    public interface Container<M extends IMember> {
        M createMember();
    }

    //The abstract class that lets you continually extend or "narrow"
    public static abstract class A<E extends A.Member> implements Container<E> {

        public static class Member implements IMember {
        }
    }

    //Here is the first class that extends the Abstract Class A
    public static class B extends A<B.Member> { //This class now Implements Container<B.Member>

        @Override
        public Member createMember() {
            return new Member();
        }

        //Since this is the first extension we will extend A.Member
        public static class Member extends A.Member {

        }

    }

    //This is an additional class that extends A but we want to extend the functionality of B.Member also.
    public static class C extends A<C.Member> { //This class now Implements Container<C.Member>


        @Override
        public Member createMember() {
            return new Member();
        }

        //C.Member properly extends B.Member
        //if this class is going to be extended this needs to be static
        public class Member extends B.Member {

        }

    }
}
```

And of course per your requirements if you remove

```
@Override
public Member createMember() {
    return new Member();
}
```

From the extending sub-classes you get a compile error.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it will fail, your class `A` implements `Container<A.Member>`, but your class `B` extends `A` but also implements `Container<B.Member>` which is like `class B extends A implements Container<A.Member> Container<B.Memeber>` , and in terms of the compiler, there is no difference between `Container<A.Member>` and `Container<B.Member>` due to type erasure, after compilation, all generics information will be lost, so there is no <……> after type erasure, only their upper bounds and lower bounds exist, your type parameters are unbounded so they will erase to the same type, after erasure, your class `B` literally looks like this `class B extends A implements Container Container` which is fundamentally wrong. You can narrow the return type on overrides which is called covariant return type, this will also create a `bridge method` in the VM to preserve porlymorphism in Generics.